# Why .NET adds extra quotes for service ImagePath when installing service

Tags: .net, service-installer

I faced very strange behaviour of .NET when it is installing a system service.

I added 2 logging calls into *OnBeforeInstall* method.
Here is what it shows just when it was entered method:

```
+ PreparingInstallation: 4 items in Parameters:
 * #0/name = TcpGw_7050
 * #1/assemblypath = D:\sandbox\x.NET\bin\Debug\TcpGwSrvc.exe
 * #2/logfile = C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Local\Temp\install-TcpGw_7050.log
 * #3/logtoconsole =
```

Here is what it shows at the end of *OnBeforeInstall* method:

```
+ ReadyToInstall: 4 items in Parameters:
 * #0/name = TcpGw_7050
 * #1/assemblypath = "D:\sandbox\x.NET\bin\Debug\TcpGwSrvc.exe" TcpGw_7050
 * #2/logfile = C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Local\Temp\install-TcpGw_7050.log
 * #3/logtoconsole =
```

But here is what was *really installed* for the *ImagePath* property of that service:

```
""D:\sandbox\x.NET\bin\Debug\TcpGwSrvc.exe" TcpGw_7050"
```

So, by unknown reasons it was enclosed whole string into *extra double quotes*! But why?
And how to fix that?

I already tried to enclose parameter with double quotes:

```
 * #1/assemblypath = "D:\sandbox\x.NET\bin\Debug\TcpGwSrvc.exe" "TcpGw_7050"
```

That did not help.

I tried to not enclose anything with double quotes:

```
 * #1/assemblypath = D:\sandbox\x.NET\bin\Debug\TcpGwSrvc.exe TcpGw_7050
```

That also did not help.

**Why it does matter**: because when *ImagePath* contains such *extra double quotes* I cannot start *service* because of error:

```
System error 87 has occurred.
The parameter is incorrect.
```

I tried to goodle this problem but not found any explanations for that.

Also a kind of *rethoric question* - why there is *such conceptual gap* in the *.NET framework design* that it does not allow to specify service *StartParameters* using some standard way? So, programmers have to use that trick with "AssemblyPath" parameter in *Context*.

Thank you in advance.

PS. It is .NET 3.5 service application.
Adding service *StartParameter* - that is done by me in a code. The question is not in adding *StartParameter* itself. The question is - why .NET framework adding *extra double quotes* there? And how to avoid that?

PPS. Yes, I know that I can write a piece of code that will open a *registry key* and modify an *ImagePath* value but I would like to avoid using such *dirty methods*, if possible I would like to do all with standard & simple features of .NET ServiceInstaller. Is it possible at all?

**Workaround:** I implemented a trick - added one quote after *assemblypath* and one quote before parameter, so now at the end of *OnBeforeInstall* method in a log output I see following:

```
 * #1/assemblypath = D:\sandbox\x.NET\bin\Debug\TcpGwSrvc.exe" "TcpGw_7050
```

With an idea that after .NET will add *quotes* around such *ImagePath* value it will became a *correct value of exe + parameters*. As I can see this *workaround* works fine. But I'm worying - what if this bug with extra quotes in .NET will be fixed in future?

Comment: I doubt that this is a bug. The assembly path is supposed to be a file path. If a path contains spaces and should be treated as one unit (for example in parameters to an application) it must be enclosed in double quotes. You're adding a parameter here, but the framework doesn't know that - it considers the entire string as a path and as such encloses it in double quotes. The real question is: does it actually matter? Does the service run fine or do you get an error because of the double quotes.

Comment: As you can see - my path does not have any spaces, so I do not understand why it is adding quotes anyway? And - yes, of course when there are _extra double quotes_ I get "error# 87. Invalid parameter", so it does matter.

Comment: @dmitry_bond - your *path* does have spaces - because as Thorsten says, it's treating the entire parameter as a path, and there's a space between `exe` and `TcpGw`.